# How to call onclick event from another controls

Tags: javascript, html

In my html page, i have a videojs player and a button. Videojs player had supported the function that when user click to it, video will be paused/played. 
So, i want to call event onclick function of videojs player by click on my button.
How can i do that?

This is my code. But it did not work.

```
<body>

  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    <track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
  </video>
  <input type="button" onclick="test();">
<script>

    function test() {
        var myPlayer = videojs("example_video_1");
        myPlayer.onclick();
    };

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function test() {
        var myPlayer = document.getElementById("example_video_1");
        myPlayer.click();
    };
```

such things become easier and more convinent if you use jquery. 
you can download it from jquery.com

Here is how the jquery would look

$("#example_video_1").click();

using jquery you can select also an element by a class or tag or any other attribute.

Comment: Thanks Neville Nazerane. But i tried both 2 ways and it could not work. When i click to the button below , i wish the player will be paused/played but nothing happen. Maybe, i had some mistakes. Here is my full html code. Please help if you find anything.

Comment: to use the second way you first need to import jquery

write the following in your head tag to import:
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

Comment: the above is not visible 
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`